# show one random list out of many on page load

Tags: php

help guys

```
<ul>
<li><p>“I should say upfront that I have never been in a cellar in my life. In fact, I can see no reason why anyone should ever go into a cellar unless there is wine involved.”</p>
<span class="author">~Rachel Hawkins, Hex Hall</span></li>
<li><p>“There is truth in wine, but you never see it listed in the ingredients on the label”</p><span class="author">~Josh Stern</span></li>
<li><p>Wine is bottled poetry.</p><span class="author">~Robert Louis Stevenson</span></li>
</ul>
```

just wanted to show 1 random list every time page refresh or loads

Comment: put it in an array and use array rand?

Answer (score 2):

this can easily be accomplished by utilizing PHPs [arrays](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php&ei=TmQIUZagH8ebrQHkt4HwCQ&usg=AFQjCNF-MzMu2teC7wnhAZOTmjhTGC9Zcg&bvm=bv.41642243,d.aWM) and the [array_rand()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php&ei=Z2QIUfTNNY_OqwGx74HoCA&usg=AFQjCNF8F0jAGopK0kfX4npnAeJVPksGfQ&bvm=bv.41642243,d.aWM)
 function. Here is a quick example:

```
<?php
 $quote_list = array("<li>Quote 1</li>", "<li>Quote 2</li>", "<li>Quote 3</li>");
  $rand_quote = $quote_list[array_rand($quote_list)];
   echo $rand_quote;
?>
```

Since PHP is only executed on the page load, everytime the page is refreshed, a new array value will be randomized and printed out from the $quote_list array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('I should say upfront that I have never been in a cellar in my life. In fact, I can see no reason why anyone should ever go into a cellar unless there is wine involved.”</p><span class="author">~Rachel Hawkins, Hex Hall</span></li>',
'<p>“There is truth in wine, but you never see it listed in the ingredients on the label”</p><span class="author">~Josh Stern</span></li>');

$rand = rand( 0, count( $array));
echo $array($rand);
```

Comment: maybe `count($array) - 1` and `$array[$rand]`... or better yet, [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand)?